# Failed to create Graph API for group changes: Status code Forbidden

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Graph API subscription creation returning a 403 for group changes. The application is a .net6 application and Graph nuget package is : Microsoft.Graph (4.11.0)

The subscription creation was working fine, but all of a sudden has stopped to work.

The error message we are getting is,

```
 Code: ExtensionError
 Message: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: ]
```

Request sent:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "changeType": "created,updated",
  "notificationUrl": "notificationurl",
  "resource": "groups/{groupid}/members",
  "expirationDateTime": "2016-03-20T11:00:00.0000000Z",
  "clientState": "SecretClientState"
}
```

The reason is not specified in the error message so it is very difficult to locate the error.

The app registration has all the relevant permission(application- Group.Read.All) to create the subscription. And as I said above it was working fine before.

The flow used is client credential flow.

Is there a way to find out the exact reason for error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have required permission ,You should need  Group.ReadWrite.All , could you please add and try again .

Hope this help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Forbidden usualy indicates that the necessary role (in this case Group.Read.All) is missing. Try to paste your Bearer token used for the authentication to jwt.ms or jwt.io - it will decode the token for you and show under "scp" or "rol" which permissions you get through this token.

You could also try to use the same token to get members of the group directly via /groups/{id}/members. If this does not work you definately have a Permission problem and the Group.Read.All/Group.ReadWrite.All isn't applied

In that case maybe take a step back and reverify if you also have granted the permissions:
-> If you use application permissions: Check Tenant wide admin grant (see AppRegistration)
-> If you use delegated permissions: verify that the user granted the Group.Read.All permissions through the interactive dialog